# Как правильно подключить метод к обработчику событий Button.click?

Tags: c#, winforms, события

Есть метод, мне надо подключить его на событие Click нескольких контролов. Пробую делать так, но ничего не происходит. Ошибок не выбивает, но метод не срабатывает по событию. В чем может быть ошибка?

```
private void ProjectPanelsVisable(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Settings.Default.PanelsProjectView = !Settings.Default.PanelsProjectView;
            Settings.Default.Save();
            SetViewForm();
        }

private void FormMainLoad(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
toolStripButton1.Click += ProjectPanelsVisable;
}
```

Comment: Все выглядит знакомо и, как говорится, "должно работать". А если точка остановки дебаггера находится на первой строке процедуры ProjectPanelsVisable() - туда тоже не передаётся управление? И еще: есть подозрение, что дело в событии toolStripButton1.Click: возможно, нужно подписываться не на клик по toolStripButton1, а на клик по его отдельным кнопкам. Грубо говоря, клик он клика на пенель кнопок - не приходит, а клик от кнопки на панели кнопок будет приходить.

Comment: Спасибо огромное! В этом и была проблема )